# join with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables in my database. I connect tables "persons"-"domains"-> id_person. Tables "domains"-"email"-> id.domain.

- persons
- domains
- email

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(e.adres_email ORDER BY d.domain_end SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS adres_email, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.domain_name ORDER BY e.adres_email SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS domain_names, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.domain_end ORDER BY e.adres_email SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS domain_ends
FROM 
    domains d
    LEFT JOIN persons p ON d.id_person = p.id
    JOIN email e ON d.id=e.id_domain
GROUP BY 
    p.id
```

Problem, when domain doesn't have a e-mail adres and when domain have more email address, because i score double domain name

Comment: Please add some sample data with your expected output. Also tag appropriate database name with your question.

Comment: screen my databases in the attachment  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRI3K.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(e.adres_email ORDER BY d.domain_end SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS adres_email, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.domain_name ORDER BY e.adres_email SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS domain_names, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.domain_end ORDER BY e.adres_email SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS domain_ends
FROM 
    domains d
    LEFT JOIN persons p ON d.id_person = p.id
    LEFT JOIN email e ON e.id = (SELECT id FROM email WHERE id_domain = d.id LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY 
    p.id, d.id
```

this query should do it.

Comment: If domain have more email address i want one result in domain, but for example i have two result

Comment: I edited my answer - should return only one email for each domain.

Comment: You don't understand me. I want return all email address in domain

Comment: No, I don't understand, maybe show results of query and show what is wrong and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: In table e-mail i have to rows "1@op.pl" and "2@op.pl". When I use this query i results twice rows  domain "op.pl" I can you use "Distinct" but when i have the same name i will have a problem. I show you on img https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCUab.jpg

Comment: I don't see how it can be done in SQL. You should group that on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty way is to use `DISTINCT` for all three:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT e.adres_email ORDER BY d.domain_end SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS adres_email, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.domain_name ORDER BY e.adres_email SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS domain_names, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.domain_end ORDER BY e.adres_email SEPARATOR '<hr>') AS domain_ends
FROM persons p LEFT JOIN
     domains d 
     ON d.id_person = p.id LEFT JOIN
     email e
     ON d.id = e.id_domain
GROUP BY p.id;
```

I'm not 100% sure the `ORDER BY`s will work.  They don't actually make that much sense to me.

Note that the `LEFT JOIN`s start with `persons`, not `domains`.  That seems to be the intent of your query.

Comment: DISTINCT works but when rows domain_name have the same domain_end